# PDF from windows empty on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf

I have a PDF that shows fine in Windows -  both in chrome browser and in Adobe Reader.
When I transfer the file to Ubuntu 16.04, and try to read it, it is blank. This happens both in okular, in chrome, and in the default PDF reader.

Why would that happen? How can I read the PDF file?

Comment: I've also tried downloading adobe reader for linux - same thing happened

Comment: Can this pdf file be made accessible to us? Perhaps the file uses fonts not available on your system? What does `strings my.pdf | grep FontName` show (replacing `my.pdf` with whatever your pdf file is named)?

Comment: Here is the file https://bit.ly/2yUyyeq

Comment: You command shows FontNames " Symbol", "/Calibri","/Arial", "/Calibri,Bold", "/Arial,Bold"

Comment: I've downloaded the missing fonts and it solved the problem.
Thanks!